# Vundle does not install vim plugins

Tags: vim

I was trying to install vim plugins but it always doesn't work. Here is my `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

" set up Vundle
" let Vundle manage Vundle
" required!
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
"plugins list
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'jalvesaq/R-Vim-runtime'
call vundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
syntax on
```

And when I ran `:PluginInstall`, only `VundleVim/Vundle.vim` was installed (see below). I have tried many ways that I can find online but still can't fix it. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: If you did not reload your vimrc after adding the plugins and running `:PluginInstall`, then Vundle will only install the Plugins defined when vim started up. To reload your vimrc, you can run `:source %` or `:so %` with your vimrc open in vim, then run `:PluginInstall`. You can also just restart vim.

Comment: You could also try adding `syntax off` before you call vundle, then turn it back on after vundle is finished; your current code already does that part. I'm not sure whether `syntax` defaults to `on` or `off`, and `:help syntax` doesn't seem to say, but it couldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks! Your comments were very helpful.

Comment: For anyone else who comes across, delete the `.vim` directory. If deleting from the command line, delete with `$ rm -Rf ~/.vim` or wherever that `.vim` folder is, then follow the instructions from `https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim` From step 2-4, assuming you already have git installed, and the default directory being the one mentioned in step 1

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, vim into ~/.vimrc and run `:source %` and then `:PluginInstall` worked for me.